# Limit number of images in a nextgen gallery

Tags: wordpress, nextgen-gallery

I am using the nextgen gallery plugin for [WordPress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress). I am making a page in which I want to get the nextgen gallery by id and limit the number of images in it to 2. The code I am using to get the gallery is:

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$gallery = get_post_meta (get_the_ID(), 'Gallery', false);
$successes = $gallery[0]; /* Where $array is the variable holding the result */
$gallery_id= $successes[0];
echo do_shortcode('[nggallery id='.$gallery_id.']');
```

There are six images in the gallery and they are used in the original post. This is just a tour post so I want to limit the number of pictures here. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following shortcodes:

**1.**

```
echo do_shortcode("[nggallery id=$gallery_id images=2]");
```

the `images` parameter controls the number of displayed images. `0` means show all. You will also get some pagination links to navigate through gallery's images. I haven't found an option to hide them, so if they are unnecessary you can hide them via css (`display: none`).

**2.**

```
echo do_shortcode("[random max=2 id=$gallery_id]");
```

which displays **randomly** maximum 2 pictures from your gallery.

---

I also recommend the following links:

NextGEN Gallery Shortcodes, var 2.0 and up:
http://www.nextgen-gallery.com/nextgen-gallery-shortcodes/

NextGEN Legacy Shortcodes:
http://www.nextgen-gallery.com/help/shortcodes/

Undocumented NextGEN Gallery shortcodes:
http://www.ralph-kemps.eu/2013/03/19/undocumented-nextgen-gallery-shortcodes/